# Entity Framework data modelling: 2 foreign keys and a primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, npgsql, composite-primary-key

I have the following tables:

```
public class Event {
  public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Participant{
  public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Registration{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int EventId {get;set;}
  public int PaticipantId {get;set;}
}
```

I have the Registration Id as a primary key, but how do I make sure that the eventid and particpantid is unique? I've thought of the composite key, but I needed a Id property on the registration as I will need that as a foreign key on another class / table.

for anyone curious about my dbcontext it's like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Participant)
                .WithMany(u => u.Events)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParticipantId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Event)
                .WithMany(u => u.Participants)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.EventId);
```

Comment: you want the combination eventId and participantId to be unique? A unique key on those two columns in the database will guarantee this, or isn't this what you asked?

Comment: you'r talking about composite keys? i was thinking about that but i need a separate unique id besides their combination as an id. that's what the Registration.Id is for. But I need to make sure that the EventId and ParticipantId is unique.

Comment: Well your RegistrationId is your primary key. By default postgres will make a unique constraint for this column. Then you add a unique key on the columns EventId and ParticipantId on top of that (in your database https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-unique.html. This way your registrationId is unique and the combination EventId,ParticipantId is also unique. If you're using entity framework migrations you can indicate in your dbcontext class that you want a unique key on those two columns and let Entity Framework generate the migration for you (or add them manually to a migration)

Comment: how do i grab the Id created? I will need that Id for a many to many relationship to another table

Comment: For many to many relations on your registration table you use your primary key (Id), there is no need for an extra id for this... your unique key will prevent duplicate entries in your registration table and you won't use it for tables referencing your registration table, you should use the primary key (Id) for this

Comment: correct. but i need the combination of eventid and participantid to be unique. is it possible to do that on the database? or should i be doing that on my data access layer (EF)?

Answer (score 0):

Create another table that contains EventId and PaticipantId as Composite key then put that table id into your Registration table.

```
public class Event {
  public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Participant{
  public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class NewTable{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int EventId  {get;set;}
   public int PaticipantId {get;set;}
}

public class Registration{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int NewTableId {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: did you mean to have an Id on the NewTable? it seems like the registration table already if you do. I'm going to need the Newtable to have a unique combination of the EventId and ParticipantId. Let's say that the NewTable is what it is. How do I make that composite key with the Id that will increment every insert?

Comment: why do you need to make Registration table's Id become primary key because it will increase every time?

Comment: yes, i will need that for a many to many relationship to another table as well

Comment: it doesn't have to be primary key in order to do that.

Comment: I see, so how do I do that on my class then? just do composite key on eventid and participantid and then on the id property, how do i make it so that the database will be updated with a sequence? i'm doing this codefirst btw and just updating the table using entity migration

Comment: you don't do that on your code, you do it in the database. when you adding new row database will taking care of this situation. By the way which database are you using.

Answer (score 0):

There is actualy MANY ways to make sure that the combination of EventId and PaticipantId is unique with or without even touching your model.

It can be set in your DB : you can declare a combination of two field UNIQUE and then catch the error inside your application and deal with it like you want.

You can also validate directly inside your application with a function that check if the combination exist. (return false if it does exist)

You can also add ANOTHER field in your model, a string representing both ids in the same fiels, and declare it unique

In fact, there are tons of solutions for your problem... Choose what is easier for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a unique key on the combination of columns EventId and ParticipantId

Since you are using EF migrations, you can add the unique key to your model and let Entity Framework generate a new migration for you afterwards. This migration will then add a unique key to your database. Depending on your Entity Framework version this will be different.

In Entity Framework Core 1.0.0 this is straightforward:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>().HasIndex(x => new { x.ParticipantId, x.EventId}).IsUnique();
```

When using Entity Framework 6 you can use annotations or fluent api (although quite verbose):

With annotations:

```
public class Registration
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  [Index("UQ_Registration_EventId_ParticipantId", 1, IsUnique = true)]
  public int EventId {get;set;}
  [Index("UQ_Registration_EventId_ParticipantId", 2, IsUnique = true)]
  public int PaticipantId {get;set;}
}
```

Or with the fluent API:

```
string uniqueIndex = "UQ_Registration_EventId_ParticipantId";

modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>().Property(t => t.EventId)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
        new IndexAnnotation(
            new IndexAttribute(uniqueIndex)
            {
                IsUnique = true,
                Order = 1
            }
        )
    );

modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>().Property(t => t.ParticipantId)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
        new IndexAnnotation(
            new IndexAttribute(uniqueIndex)
            {
                IsUnique = true,
                Order = 2
            }
        )
    );
```

Comment: ok, that seems straightforward, one question tho, the uniqueIndex, is that something I need to generate on my own? also, will the id be autogenerated?

Comment: There is no autogenerated id. The unique key is just a constraint prohibiting duplicate EventId and ParticipantId combinations from appearing in the table. It doesn't have an Id itself. Unique constraints ensure that the data contained in a column, or a group of columns (in this case your two foreign key ids EventId and ParticipantId), is unique among all the rows in the table.